# pass a value of a string to another class

Tags: c#

I have this class "connessionedatabase.cs":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public partial class connesionedatabase : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        
        public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {
            string valuemenu = e.Item.Value;
            Response.Redirect("cruscottodatiaccuratezza.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

In this class I take the value `e.item.value` of a menu and save it into a string. This string so, contains a value, but I want to pass it to another class "cruscottoaccuratezza.cs" because I want to to do a switch control. How can i do it? It's a method?

Comment: `cruscottoaccuratezza.cs` seems to be a file not a class. You can set a property, use a method or whatever you need

Comment: But i can't access to the real value.

Comment: Response.Redirect("cruscottodatiaccuratezza.aspx" + "?myvalue=" + valuemenu)

Comment: @Dai because I'm doing a thesis project! is it possible to have an answer without inappropriate comments? thank you!

Comment: @fabio251996 It's not an inappropriate comment. I'm trying to help you by pointing out that you're making things much harder for yourself than you need to. I accept there are some good reasons (albeit, very few) for using WebForms in 2021, so if you don't have a good reason then I'd prefer to spend my time to assist you with migrating to a _non-obsolete_ framework rather than _enabling_ you to build your own timebomb. It's no different than if you posted Win16 code with `far` pointers in a C++ question: _fundamentals, like platform choice, are important_.

Comment: I think the point about webforms is reasonable; By all means don't develop in a leading/bleeding edge technology because there isn't a lot of support/wide knowledgebase, and stuff will be shifting around a lot (Blazor's just settling down).. But equally maybe don't start new dev in a very old framework either, for similar reasons - fewer people around that know the intricacies of it, less support for hosting it, the thrust of modern dev efforts going into newer technologies/you're stuck for longe rwith any bugs you find.. Doubtless there are lots of old tutorials out there, but..

Comment: @CaiusJard yes I was over the phone while writing and my multitask chip is a little obsolete XD

Comment: ..there are probably a load of tutorials floating around that tell people to write SQL like `"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE ID = " + Request.Form["username"]` (because people keep showing up doing it)

Comment: All in, don't be afraid to give Blazor a go; it's really nice, and makes for quite a slick end product with little effort, especially if you use a good framework to sling your pages together. Writing a "switch control" (whatever that is) might already have been done, and popping one on your page be as simple as `<SomeFrameworkSwitch Items="@_someArrayOfItems" />`

Comment: i resolved making static valuemenu.

Comment: @fabio251996 What do you mean by "static valuemenu"?

Comment: @Dai you know when you log into your bank and see someone else's account... "But `static string LoggedInUserAccountNumber` seemed like such a quick fix, and it worked when one guy tested it in the dev system..!"

Comment: @CaiusJard That's what I was afraid of.... Have the _civic-minded_ folks at Facebook developed a way to throw textbooks about _professional engineering ethics_ directly into people's faces over the Internet yet?

Comment: @Dai You mean in the way they* sway elections by throwing "ethical" adverts in people's faces already? I think we've got to await an inversion of the definition of "ethical" in the company handbook. I wonder how they're progressing that one.. *cough cough I meant "some naughty Coughbridge Analyticough cough uses the platform totally unbeknownst to innocent FB", cough.. Oh my, this cough.. Feels like it'll never end